# Is speed of a programming language factor to be considered for AI /machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Is speed of programming language  factor to be considered for AI /machine learning? ..if it does than how much ??

Edit:
By speed I mean speed of execution

Comment: Programming languages don't have speeds.

Comment: What do you mean by the "speed of [a] programming language?"  How long it takes to learn?  How easy it is to write a complex algorithm?  How long it takes to run (supposedly) equivalent algorithm implementations in different languages?

Comment: By speed I mean speed of execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of factors that go into [selecting a programming language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc168615.aspx).  The purpose of the AI is more important to selecting the language than the AI itself.  If you really care about how many instructions can be executed each second, Assembly is going to be the fastest.  But if you took a second to think about how to implement an AI algorithm in Assembly, you suddenly care much less about how quickly the AI executes/stabilizes.  Realistically, if you are just starting AI and doing very simple algorithms you could use an interpreted language such as Python and never know the difference.

So to answer your question directly: no.